# Get list of connected devices to an hotspot using NetworkManager

Tags: c, linux, networkmanager

Is there a way to retrieve IP and MAC address of devices connected to a Wi-Fi hotspot/access point using NetworkManager (`nmcli` or even better via C API)?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question, but for me it was enough to display that info on terminal. I didn't find anything in documentation, but the apt package (`apt info network-manager`) on Ubuntu has a dependency on dnsmasq-base. So opening `htop` I saw that NetworkManager (in my case) uses dnsmasq for dhcp server.

With htop(or similar, you can press `t` to sort by parent processes) you can look for `/usr/sbin/dnsmasq` running. there you will be able to see all the arguments it is given.
One of them is `--dhcp-leasefile`. You can use that as a starting pointer.

In my case it was`leasefile=/var/lib/NetworkManager/dnsmasq-wlo1.leases`

There also was argument `--dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq-shared.d` that may help you to configure dnsmasq if that's required

Comment: My solution was using wpa_supplicant (in C) to get MAC address of connected devices and then matching them with information in `/proc/net/arp` to get their IP address. Maybe not the best solution, but it seems to work